# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away only for magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

The MySQL is regularly going away for Magento 2 only. While working, if I refresh cache, then it shows gone.

I can login to the MySQL and do all the queries. It is working. Also, the local Magento 1 will work properly. Only the Magento 2 has a problem.

```
 3 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
    Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
    Exception #2 (Exception): Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/store2/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 129

    Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
    #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/store2/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
    #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/store2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(340): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
    #2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/store2/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
    #3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/store2/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SHOW TABLES', Array)
```

Comment: Please check your Mysql connection again with user name and pwd.

Comment: I have checked mysql connection. When, i get the error in the magento2 website, i can open in another tab magento1 website connected to separate database in localhost. Able to login to mysql command line with the magento2 database, and execute queries. i am using macbook for local development with magento1 and magento2 instances. Migrating modules from magento1 to magento2.

Comment: You can try [these suggestions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_mysql_table-open-cache.html).

Comment: Tried it, but of no luck. Still getting the error, regularly.

Comment: i have uninstalled mysql and installed mariadb. Now it is working properly, and has not given the error till now.

Comment: It's better to read the doc: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_mysql_table-open-cache.html

Comment: It is not while installation. The installation was fine, but the problem comes when browsing through the admin pages. But, now there is no problem, as I have shifted to Mariadb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the mysql and installing mariadb, the problem has gone.
I think, there was some problem in my mysql. Didn't try re-installing mysql.